# VC++ Shortcut to look at memory at an address

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2015, I can look at the memory in my program by bringing out the memory window (alt+6) during debugging, copying a pointer's address, and pasting it into the window.  This shows me the surrounding memory, which is my favourite feature of the debugger.

This is a lot of steps though for such a frequent task, and has to be done for each address.

Is there an easier way of seeing the memory a pointer is pointing at, along with surrounding memory?  Maybe a shortcut I'm missing, or a setting that causes the hover dialog to display more than just one "object" a pointer addresses?

Comment: The obvious way: just type the name of your pointer variable into the "Address" field of the memory window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when developing C++ project in debug mode.

Apart from Memory window, we also have [auto window,local window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2017) and watch window.The layout for me looks like below:

[image]

**Drag** the variable to memory window and you can get the memory the variable refers to, also with its surrounding memory.And for pointer, it also works to automatically enter the address into memory window.

If it works or not, please give me a feedback.

Comment: That does work, I didn't realize variable names could be dragged like that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Have a nice day!